# How can I avoid a memory leak in this function?

Tags: cocoa, memory-management

I'm trying to guess the mime type for a specific file, and I have this code:

```
- (NSString *)fileMIMEType:(NSString *)file {
  CFStringRef UTI = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, (__bridge CFStringRef)[file pathExtension], NULL);
  CFStringRef MIMEType = UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(UTI, kUTTagClassMIMEType);
  CFRelease(UTI);
  return (__bridge NSString *)MIMEType;
}
```

During Analyze Xcode (5) complains that there's a potential leak of an object stored into 'MIMEType'.

How can I rewrite this utility method to avoid leaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a `CFStringRef` which is not managed by ARC, you need to *transfer* ownership of that reference to ARC so that it will release it when needed. To do that you use `__bridge_transfer`, the `__bridge` you have used does not transfer ownership which will result in a leak.